# How can I create a Lua function, that represents my target's debuff damage?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I play World of Warcraft and ofcors I use Weak Aura. There is an option in the addon where I can tipe a function and the addon runs my scriop.
I would like to create a function thet represents the damage of `MyOrderedDebuff` as a single integer value.

```
function DebuffDamageOfTarget()
    return target.debuffs['MyOrderedDebuff'].damage
end
```

I ment somethig like this but I don't know how the sintx is or how the debuff are reachable.

Comment: Besides passing `target` as a parameter, it's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: I would look up [UnitDebuff](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_UnitDebuff), but this will only tell you basic info like the name of the debuff and how many stacks are applied.  It won't tell you how much damage it has done or will do.